# unable to assemble using ml/ml64

Tags: gcc, x86-64, masm

I've been using Visual Studio to assemble and link cpp programs that include masm (.asm) files. I want to be able to do this myself, on the command line. I used the ml.exe that Visual Studio provides to assemble my masm code (at `Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\Hostx86\x86\ml.exe`).

However, when I try to compile my project with `gcc main.cpp fib.obj -o main`, I get an error saying that the .obj architecture does not match the target architecture (`i386 architecture of input file 'fib.obj' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output`).

So my question is, simply, how do I compile this project?

#### What I've Tried

The two things that I've done to get different errors (which I think are more promising) are (1) to utilize the ml64 executable from `...\Hostx86\x64\ml64.exe` or `...\Hostx64\x64\ml64.exe`, and (2) to use the `-m32` option for gcc.

##### ml64

Using ml64 I have been unable to assemble my masm code. with the following source file, ml64 spits out this response:

```
; int fib(int);
    .386
    .model flat, c
    
    .code
fib proc uses ebx ecx, i:dword
    mov eax, 0 ; current fib number
    mov ebx, 1 ; next fib number
    while_1:
        cmp i, 0
        jle while_1_end

        ; add eax -> ebx and mov previous ebx into eax
        mov ecx, ebx ; store new current fib number
        add ebx, eax ; sum previous fib numbers
        mov eax, ecx ; set eax to current fib value

        dec i
        jmp while_1
    while_1_end:
    ; the ith fib number is in eax
    ret

fib endp
end
```

```
...\fib> ml64 fib.asm
Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler (x64) Version 14.29.30136.0    
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.   

 Assembling: fib.asm
fib.asm(2) : error A2008:syntax error : .
fib.asm(3) : error A2008:syntax error : .
fib.asm(6) : error A2008:syntax error : ebx
fib.asm(24) : fatal error A1010:unmatched block nesting : fib
```

I presume that `.386` isn't right for a x64 target, but removing it changes the error very little (it only removes the syntax error line 2).

I don't really want to use x64 assembly if it isn't the same as x32, but I'll use this solution if it works. I think my second option is more promising.

##### gcc -m32

I don't believe I can tell gcc to build to a 32-bit target because I don't have 32-bit versions of the libraries. When running `gcc -m32 main.cpp fib.obj` I get `cannot find -lmingw32`, `cannot find -lgcc`, `cannot find -lgcc_ex`, etc. Should I get these libraries, and if so, where do I find them? It seems a bit awful to download 32-bit libraries on my x64 computer just to assemble masm, and I don't think I should have to, seeing as Visual Studio is able to compile my project simply by setting the target to Win32.

Is there a different way of telling gcc to target 32-bit architecture, or are the libraries perhaps hidden in the Visual Studio files, or something else? I'm pretty sure that if I could get gcc to target x32, it would solve my problem, because Visual Studio targets x32, and when I change the target to x64 I get the same error I have been getting (`module machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'`).

Comment: Per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/directives-reference?view=msvc-160), I don't believe ml64 supports the `.386` directive.  In fact, I believe `.model` is also 32bit only.

Comment: ok, I can remove those directives. It doesn't solve the other two errors.

Comment: It's my understanding that `uses` results in *The assembler generates prologue code to push registers onto the stack upon entry.* But I don't believe x64 allows you to push 32bit registers, only 64bit.  Have you tried `rbx rcx`?

Comment: I will try this once I get back to my computer.

Comment: I’m starting to realize that this post unintentionally contains two unrelated questions: how to write x64 assembly, and how to use gcc to link x86 assembly. For me, I’d rather get the second question answered; I should ask that as a separate question.